# How to access windows mounted drive with Java?

Tags: java, windows, path, unc

I have a WD My Cloud at home. I can access it with my laptop from the file explorer just by typing `Z:\path\to\image.jpg`.

I'm writing a Java program that would read the image content located on this little cloud.

Here is my code:

```
Path p =Paths.get("\\\\192.168.1.2\\z$\\path\\to\\image.jpg");

try {
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(p);

    // Process data here...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

This program fails with the below exception :

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \\192.168.1.2\z$\path\to\image.jpg: Nom de réseau introuvable.

*"Nom de réseau introuvable"* : “Network name not found”

I tried other paths without success:

- \\localhost\z$\path\to\image.jpg
- \\127.0.0.1\z$\path\to\image.jpg
- \\MyPcName-PC\z$\path\to\image.jpg
- Z:/path/to/image.jpg

What am I missing ?

**Windows 10**
**Java 8**

Comment: UNC or SMB?  I've had issues with SMB on Windows 8+ due to changes in the security management system

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng without success : something like `SmbFile sf = new SmbFile(pathHere)`. This constructor is deprecated and I didn't find an example with a non deprecated constructor. Today, I read `Path` could handle such paths. So far, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Format the string in the Paths.get argument similar as is shown below.

```
package access.mounted.drive;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * @author Charles
 */
public class AccessMountedDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path p =
        Paths.get("E:\\\\Photos Grandparents\\Scan0166a Rose Pincoffs.jpg");

        try {
            int i=0;
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(p);
            System.out.println("File size in bytes:" + data.length);
            // Process data here...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The code raises this exception: `IOException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Z:\path\to\image.jpg`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have mounted the directory. How did you perform file operations?